# Java: Sorting an array (Part 2)

Tags: java

I understand how to sort an array by ascending and descending order, but there is a specific pattern I'm trying to create. For example, I have an array in a random order. How would I sort this array in the pattern? "smallest, largest, second smallest, second largest, thrid smallest, third largest..." etc Any ideas?

```
public class Test2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,4,2,6,9,3,65,77,33,22};
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
}     
    wackySort(array);

}


public static void wackySort(int[] nums){
    int sign = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
//This sorts the array
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length -1; j++){
            if (nums[j] > nums[j+1]){
                temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                nums[j+1] = temp;

        }
    }

}
// This prints out the new array
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
                System.out.print(" " + nums[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();

//This part attempts to fix the array into the order I want it to
            int firstPointer = 0;
            int secondPointer = nums.length -1;
            int[] newarray = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length -1; i+=2){
        newarray[i] = nums[firstPointer++];
                    newarray[i] = nums[secondPointer--];
} 
            for(int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++){
                System.out.print(" " + newarray[i]);
}


}
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't post the same question here. Check the updated answer of last post

Comment: http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html

Comment: Ok, thanks.  How do I delete this post?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to achieve this. Study this article about [Java Object Sorting Example (Comparable And Comparator)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/). it will be helpful to you.